# Click Here link shows when Ad isn't loaded

Tags: discussion

[image: Example]

If you go to a question, it usually says 'Click Here' in the place of a big Ad before it loads.  Is this something that's coded into the SO website, or is it just how the BigAds work, or is it what the person who made the Ad coded into the Ad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed it only happens with the LogMeIn Ads, so it's what the person who made the Ad coded into it.  However, I've never been quick enough to actually press *Click Here* and see if it's the same as clicking the Ad.